# How to mock Jwt bearer token for integration tests

Tags: c#, jwt

I have created a microservice using .Net 5 which has some endpoints which can only be called with a jwtBearertoken.

The `ConfigureServices` and `Configure` methods in the `StartUp` class look like this:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ConfigureDatabaseServices(services);
        ConfigureMyProjectClasses(services);
        services.AddVersioning();

        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddAuthentication(_configuration);
        // Add framework services.
        var mvcBuilder = services
            .AddMvc()
            .AddControllersAsServices();
        ConfigureJsonSerializer(mvcBuilder);
    }

        public void Configure(
        IApplicationBuilder app,
        IWebHostEnvironment webEnv,
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
        IHostApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
    {
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("Startup");

        try
        {
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                var correlationId = Guid.NewGuid();
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId = correlationId;
                context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Correlation-ID", correlationId.ToString());
                await next();
            });

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
            applicationLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(() =>
            {
                LogManager.Shutdown();
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

AuthenticationExtensions:

```
    public static class AuthenticationExtensions
    {
    public static void AddAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options     =>
        {
            options.Authority = configuration["Authorization:Authority"];
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
        });
    }
}
```

I'm using an authorization server for the microservice to validate the token.

After adding an `[Authorize]` attribute above the controllers postman returns `401 Unauthorized` and the integration tests I had created before adding Authentication also return `Unauthorized` as expected.
Now I am trying to figure out how I can change my integration tests by adding a JwtBearerToken and mocking the response from the authorization server so my tests will pass again.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: You should not mock the `Authorize` attribute even if that was possible.(I'm not sure it is possible or not) the goal of integration tests is to test the actual request/response.  I think you should generate a token for your tests.

Comment: @AliReza It's not intention to mock the `Authorize` attribute, I'm trying to mock adding a jwtbearertoken and mocking the response of the authorization server

Comment: I know I meant when you have authorization in your pipeline the behavior of your app could be different. it is better to include the token in your requests. 
but in the end, if you really need to mock the authorization. you must start to mock the entire DI

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My answer is not 100% integrated, because we will add an extra auth scheme. TL;DR: You are not testing if your auth works, but working around it.

It would be best to use an ACTUAL token, but perhaps this solution is a nice middle ground.

You could create another auth scheme like `DevBearer` where you can specify an account, for example if you send the auth header `DevBearer Customer-John`, the application would recognize you as Customer John.

I use this approach during development because it is very easy to just test different users quickly. My code looks something like this:

Startup.Auth.cs

```cs
        private void ConfigureAuthentication(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

            services
                    .AddAuthentication(options =>
                    {
                        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    })
                    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                    {
                        options.Audience = "Audience";
                        options.Authority = "Authority";
                    });

#if DEBUG
            if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                AllowDevelopmentAuthAccounts(services);
                return;
            }
#endif

            // This is custom and you might need change it to your needs.
            services.AddAuthorization();

        }


#if DEBUG
        // If this is true, you can use the Official JWT bearer login flow AND Development Auth Account (DevBearer) flow for easier testing.
        private static void AllowDevelopmentAuthAccounts(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication("DevBearer").AddScheme<DevelopmentAuthenticationSchemeOptions, DevelopmentAuthenticationHandler>("DevBearer", null);

            // This is custom and you might need change it to your needs.
            services.AddAuthorization();
        }
#endif
```

Custom Policies Hint

```
// Because my Policies/Auth situation is different than yours, I will only post a hint that you might want to use.
// I want to allow calls from the REAL flow AND DevBearer flow during development so I can easily call my API using the DevBearer flow, or still connect it to the real IDentityServer and front-end for REAL calls.

                var policyBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).RequireAuthenticatedUser();

                // The #IF adds an extra "security" check so we don't accidentally activate the development auth flow on production
#if DEBUG
                if (_allowDevelopmentAuthAccountCalls)
                {
                    policyBuilder.AddAuthenticationSchemes("DevBearer").RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                }
#endif

                return policyBuilder;
```

Auth handler

```
#if DEBUG
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace NAMESPACE
{
    public class DevelopmentAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<DevelopmentAuthenticationSchemeOptions>
    {
        public DevelopmentAuthenticationHandler(
            IOptionsMonitor<DevelopmentAuthenticationSchemeOptions> options,
            ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock)
            : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
        {
        }

        protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
        {
            if (!Context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out var authorizationHeader))
            {
                return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Unauthorized");
            }

            var auth = AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(authorizationHeader);

            if (auth.Scheme == "Bearer")
            {
                // If Bearer is used, it means the user wants to use the REAL authentication method and not the development accounts. 
                return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Bearer requests should use the real JWT validation scheme");
            }

            // Dumb workaround for NSwag/Swagger: I can't find a way to make it automatically pass "DevBearer" in the auth header.
            // Having to type DevBearer everytime is annoying. So if it is missing, we just pretend it's there.
            // This means you can either pass "ACCOUNT_NAME" in the Authorization header OR "DevBearer ACCOUNT_NAME".
            if (auth.Parameter == null)
            {
                auth = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("DevBearer", auth.Scheme);
            }

            IEnumerable<Claim> claims;
            try
            {
                var user = auth.Parameter;
                claims = GetClaimsForUser(user);
            }
            catch (ArgumentException e)
            {
                return AuthenticateResult.Fail(e);
            }

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "DevBearer");
            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

            // Add extra claims if you want to
            await Options.OnTokenValidated(Context, principal);

            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, "DevBearer");

            return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);
        }

        private static IEnumerable<Claim> GetClaimsForUser(string? user)
        {
            switch (user?.ToLowerInvariant())
            {
                // These all depend on your needs.
                case "Customer-John":
                    {
                        yield return new("ID_CLAIM_NAME", Guid.Parse("JOHN_GUID_THAT_EXISTS_IN_YOUR_DATABASE").ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.String);
                        yield return new("ROLE_CLAIM_NAME", "Customer", ClaimValueTypes.String);
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentException("Can't set specific account for local development because the user is not recognized", nameof(user));
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    public class DevelopmentAuthenticationSchemeOptions : AuthenticationSchemeOptions
    {
        public Func<HttpContext, ClaimsPrincipal, Task> OnTokenValidated { get; set; } = (context, principal) => { return Task.CompletedTask; };
    }
}
#endif
```

With something like this, you could do an API call with an authorization header like `DevBearer Customer-John` and it would add the ID and role claim to the context, allowing auth to succeed :)

Comment: You're right that I don't want to test that authentication works and want to work around it.
So this way I can just add the bearer token to the `Authorization` header of the request?

Comment: Like this?
`Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "DevBearer Customer-John)`?

Comment: Yeah, that is how you could call it :). If you have any issues with this approach, let me know. If it works and you are happy with this approach, please accept it as an answer. 

If it DOES work, I would still ask you why you want to skip the auth part in your integration test. An integration test should test multiple parts of your system working together. Why do you not want your auth system to be included?

Comment: I don't necessarily want to skip the authentication part, I want to be able to mock it and test a situation where it passes authentication.
I have a special `TestServer` with authentication and setup a client for this particular purpose.