# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC Integration Tests - Authorization

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, integration-testing, .net-6.0

Here is my problem. I can't seem to manage to create an integration test that requires an authenticated user. I use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing` for testing. Here is my test:

[image]

As seen the client has the role "Patient" and a UserId. Here are my helpers:

```
public class TestClaimsProvider
{
        public IList<Claim> Claims { get; }

        public TestClaimsProvider(IList<Claim> claims)
        {
            Claims = claims;
        }

        public TestClaimsProvider()
        {
            Claims = new List<Claim>();
        }

        public static TestClaimsProvider WithAdminClaims()
        {
            var provider = new TestClaimsProvider();
            provider.Claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));
            provider.Claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Admin user"));
            provider.Claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrator"));

            return provider;
        }

        public static TestClaimsProvider WithUserClaims()
        {
            var provider = new TestClaimsProvider();
            provider.Claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));
            provider.Claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Patient"));
            provider.Claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Patient"));

            return provider;
        }
}
```

This also:

```
public class TestAuthHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{
    private readonly IList<Claim> _claims;

    public TestAuthHandler(IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options, 
            ILoggerFactory logger, 
            UrlEncoder encoder, 
            ISystemClock clock, TestClaimsProvider claimsProvider) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
        _claims = claimsProvider.Claims;
    }

    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(_claims, "Test");
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, "Test");

        var result = AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);

        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }
}
```

And:

```
public static class WebApplicationFactoryExtensions
{
    public static WebApplicationFactory<T> WithAuthentication<T>(this WebApplicationFactory<T> factory, TestClaimsProvider claimsProvider) where T : class
    {
        return factory.WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
        {
            builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddAuthentication("Test")
                        .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, TestAuthHandler>("Test", op => { });

            services.AddScoped<TestClaimsProvider>(_ => claimsProvider);
        });
    });
}

public static HttpClient CreateClientWithTestAuth<T>(this WebApplicationFactory<T> factory, TestClaimsProvider claimsProvider) where T : class
{
    var client = factory.WithAuthentication(claimsProvider).CreateClient(new WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions
    {
        AllowAutoRedirect = false
    });

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Test");

    return client;
}
```

These are based on this subject https://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet-core-integration-tests-users-roles/. Although I am not using the `FakeStartup` class that he has pointed in previous threads. Also I have tried the authentication from the docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0#customize-the-client-with-withwebhostbuilder but it is the same.

Here is my action method in the controller:

```
[Authorize(Roles = PatientRoleName)]
public async Task<IActionResult> MakePatientAppointment()
{
    var patient = await this.patientService.GetPatientByUserIdAsync(this.User.GetId());

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(patient.FirstName) || 
        string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(patient.LastName) || 
        string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(patient.Phone))
    {
        this.TempData["Message"] = PatientProfileIsNotFinishedMsg;

        return RedirectToAction("Finish", "Patient", new { area = "" });
    }

    var viewModel = new PatientAppointmentCreateModel
            {
                DoctorId = await this.doctorService.GetDoctorId(),
                AppointmentCauses = await this.appointmentCauseService.GetAllCauses()
            };

    return View(viewModel); 
}
```

From debugging the test the response redirect is to `/Identity/Login`, so from what I am understanding the user is not logged in. How can I refactor the code to manage to get the user authenticated?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mock Jwt bearer token for integration tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69188522/how-to-mock-jwt-bearer-token-for-integration-tests)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Updated for ASP.net 6

The *top-level statements* new feature of C# 10, provided the unification of the `Startup` and `Program` classes into a single `Program` class, and because of that (among other things like the new *minimal hosting model*), the creation of the `WebApplicationFactory` has changed, starting with the way to change the visibility of the `Program` class to the *TestFixture* (since it now doesn't contain a namespace due to the top-level statements feature)...

And the documentation has been updated as such, however, the way we registered the `AuthenticationHandler` to create an impersonated client for authorization has also changed - but the documentation (at least so far) doesn't address this.

So if we register the `AuthenticationHandler` as we did until ASP.net 5, now in ASP.net 6, we get a 401 Unauthorized (because it's not working anymore).

After a lot of research I found the solution:

Now, it's necessary to make explicit the `AuthenticationOptions` settings in the `WebApplicationFactory` according to the settings you have in your WebApi, in my case:

```
{
    o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "Test";
    o.DefaultChallengeScheme = "Test";
}
```

[image]